# String as a variable (Dot-notation instead bracket-notation)?

Tags: c#

In *javascript*, properties of objects can be accessed using dot-notation instead of bracket-notation -- `object.propertyName` can be used in place of `object["propertyName"]`.

**How can I do this in C#?**

As an example, say I have a helper class to return values from a resource file:

```
public static class ResourceHelper
    {
        public static string get(string resourceName)
        {
            uint language = SPContext.Current.Web != null ? SPContext.Current.Web.Language : 1033;
            return SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:" + resourceName, "Comp.Dept.Proj.Farm\\Resources", language);
        }
    }
```

So here, instead of

```
ResourceHelper.get("SQL_CONNECTION_STRING")
```

would it be possible to do something like

```
ResourceHelper.SQL_CONNECTION_STRING
```

instead?

If yes, how? I feel this will make the code easier to read, IMO.

Comment: Properties are *always* accessed with dot notation in C# - your problem is that you don't have a property.

Comment: Be aware that while in JavaScript, the two ways of accessing `propertyName` are essentially the same behind the scenes (and consequently, one speaks of *notations*), in C# the two ways of accessing something (a property or a return value of a parametrized function) are fundamentally different and get evaluated at different times in the code lifetime.

Comment: Generally, that's not possible out of the box with a strongly typed language like C# (thank god!). It in fact _is_ possible with variables of type `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a property for that.

In ResourceHelper.cs, add

```
public string SQL_CONNECTION_STRING
get{return get("SQL_CONNECTION_STRING"); }
```

Answer (score 6):

You may create a Property like this

```
public static string SqlConnectionString {
  get {
    return get("SQL_CONNECTION_STRING");
  }
}
```

in your class but i guess you're looking for something doing that automagically...